# How to mock a statically referenced assembly?

Tags: c#, mocking, .net-assembly

In C# I have an **application.exe**, which uses **library.dll** (a compile-time reference). Now **library.dll** is used to communicate with some hardware, which is very slow. Is it possible to create another project in visual studio, which will also create **library.dll**, but it would be a mock. I want to be able to simply replace the dll file without recompiling the exe or replacing the reference in visual studio. I know I can load a dll at run time, but is it possible to replace a statically referenced dll without causing:

```
FileLoadException: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

(I do not use strong names)

Comment: How many different classes do you reference in library.dll ?

Comment: The dll contains an internal class which implements an interface (defined elsewhere). It also contains a public static factory, which instantiates the internal class in the correct way. The mock would also have a factory class with the same signature returning the same interface, but it would instantiate the mock class instead.

Comment: Can you change the design so the application.exe has a reference to the interface but not to library.dll ? If so you could use a light-weight container, such as spring. You wouldn't have a reference neither on library.dll nor on the mock.

Comment: That is how I do it now. I dynamically load the dll, just as spring does. I didn't use spring itself, because I thought it would be an overkill to include spring just to load one tiny dll with one class in it. But I was wondering if this is the only solution or is there a better one. One bad thing about dynamic linking is that Visual Studio won't notice at compile time that some dependency is missing.

Comment: The client code depends on an interface, so any modification in the interface will be reported by the compiler. As for the implementation assembly, the compiler should report an error if the interface is modified.

Answer (score 1):

it will be going to be pita, trying to mimic a dll just for mocking purpose.

i suggest you put in feature in your code, a flag to indicate wheteher the code should run as mock mode, which will not calling/invoke the dll/reference at all.